# How to restrict user to defult view of the sharepoint list?

Tags: permissions, list-view

I am using Sharepoint 2007
We have created three views to a List.
Can I restrict user to access only default view of list?

Thanks and Regards,
Rushikesh

Comment: Why? As I am asking question related to Sharepoint Custom List

Comment: @Rushikesh: but it seems not to be programming related.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of Admins you have, you could make the one view public, and the other two views private.

Or you could have one view with audience targeted content.

Comment: Hi SkinnyE, How to make view private? Thanks Rushikesh